# Android Architecture Component(LiveData): How to clear all value from LiveData once it updates a textview

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

suppose I created mutableLivedata variable(an observer), and I updated a textview through it, now I wouldlike to clear value that was sent by livedata once it updates textview like I just created Livedata variable and its fresh in initial stage, it has no value. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what it was made for?

Answer (score 4):

You would not do this.

One of the main reasons to use `LiveData` is to have other components be able to observe the contents of the `LiveData`.

So for example, let's say you use a `LiveData` to keep track of how many times a counter is pressed. You use a `TextView` to observe this `LiveData` so you can display the number of the counter whenever the `LiveData` updates.

This is the expected use of `LiveData`.

With what you want to do, the moment you set the contents of `LiveData` to be empty, the `TextView` that is observing that `LiveData` will also update itself to become empty too.

If you want to reset `LiveData` after you've displayed it's value in a `TextView`, then `LiveData` isn't meant for what you intend to do.

Simply using a `String` would be easier and more efficient.

Edit:

But if you still want to do this, as long as your `LiveData` is a `MutableLiveData`, you can use the `setValue()` method to set a default value.